# Remove labels from within data.frame and tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have used named vectors to make a data.frame. When I convert this data.frame to a tibble, I end up with named lists instead of regular columns. How can I remove these names?

example data

```r
ww = structure(list(is_character = list(`labA` = 1, `labB` = 1, `labC` = 1), 
                    is_numeric = list(`labA` = 0, `labB` = 0, `labC` = 0),
                    is_logical = list(`labA` = 0, `labB` = 0, `labC` = 0),
                    column_name = c("labA", "labB", "labC")),
               row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Everything looks fine when viewed as a dataframe. `as.data.frame(ww)` returns the following:

```
  is_character is_numeric is_logical column_name
1            1          0          0        labA
2            1          0          0        labB
3            1          0          0        labC
```

But when converted to a tibble I end up with named lists instead of plain columns. `as_tibble(ww)` returns the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  is_character is_numeric   is_logical   column_name
  <named list> <named list> <named list> <chr>      
1 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    labA       
2 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    labB       
3 <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    <dbl [1]>    labC
```

I don't want to work with named lists in my tibble, I want to work with plain numeric columns. How can I do this?

I have tried to make the original data.frame from unnamed lists, but this introduces other problems. So, removing the names is preferable. I have made several attempts with `unname` with no success.

Comment: In this particular case, you can simply do: `as_tibble(ww) %>% unnest(everything())`. However, I'm not sure if your example data fully captures your actual use-case

Comment: Your data was always a set of `list`s - see `str(ww)` - how something appears when printed to the console and how it is stored are not always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of simple approaches:

```
as_tibble(ww) %>% mutate(across(everything(), unlist))
```

Or

```
as_tibble(ww) %>% unnest(everything())
```

Both approaches produce:

```
  is_character is_numeric is_logical column_name
         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      
1            1          0          0 labA       
2            1          0          0 labB       
3            1          0          0 labC
```

Of note, your `is_character` column is not character, and your `is_logical` column is not logical. However, if your input data was this:

```
ww = structure(list(is_character = list(`labA` = "a", `labB` = "b", `labC` = "c"), 
                    is_numeric = list(`labA` = 0, `labB` = 0, `labC` = 0),
                    is_logical = list(`labA` = T, `labB` = F, `labC` = T),
                    column_name = c("labA", "labB", "labC")),
               row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

then the above approaches would produce this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  is_character is_numeric is_logical column_name
  <chr>             <dbl> <lgl>      <chr>      
1 a                     0 TRUE       labA       
2 b                     0 FALSE      labB       
3 c                     0 TRUE       labC
```